# Lookups in SharePoint Workflow Emails

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, email

I've created a workflow that sends an email to all users when any new item is added to my "Payroll Processing" list.

I want to be able to display the `Client Name` in the email that gets sent.

The `Client Name` is a lookup from my `Clients` list.

If I use `Current Item > Client Name`, my workflow will not run. I'm guessing because the actual client name sits in my `Clients` list.

Any pointers would be great.